# Not allowed to set full control security permission on drive

Tags: windows

I have looked at my second drive root security permitions and found that all actions (read/write/execute ..) are enabled is enabled for `Authenticated Users, Users (GM\Users), Administrators (GM\Administrators)` :

[image]

I went down deeper to some `Data access` folder and found that `GM\Users` don't have full aces to that folder. Also, I found that I can't set security permissions for that folder (they are grayed).

How it might happen that I got folder with limited permissions ?
How I can set full control permissions ? I'm using local user that has in Administrators group in this computer, but can't edit folders security things anyway.

[image]

UPD

I tried to set full control on folder for `GM\Users`, but got error:

```
Failed enumerate objects in the container. Access is denied
```

After clicking this error I found that permissions are set. How to explain such situation?

[image]

Comment: Advanced -> Change Permissions -> Add. Or alternatively under advances -> Owner set to yourself.

Comment: Nothing I see is unusual.  You own the root directory but not one of the child directories.  Take ownership of any file or folder with your Administrator user then add/remove users and/or user groups to the ACL.  “How it might happen that I got folder with limited permissions?”  A previlaged user removed permissions.  You sure this isn’t intentional?